# My JS code is still keep saying nothing(?) instead of the correct rgb colors, and don't know why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

Well, I want to make an rgb color guessing game in JS (+HTML,CSS) and in the for loop, the next line is giving me just space back:

```
console.log(this.style.background);
```

Here is the full JS code:

```
var colors = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var rgbColors = [
    "rgb(21,54,217)",
    "rgb(32,255,0)",
    "rgb(43,255,255)",
    "rgb(32,68,103)",
    "rgb(147,54,24)",
    "rgb(255,54,217)"
];
var pickedColor = rgbColors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i].style.backgroundColor = rgbColors[i];
    colors[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(this.style.background);
    })
}
```

And here is my HTML if it's necessary:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>RGB guessing game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> guessing game</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="rgbGame.css" />
    <script src="rgbGame.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess my CSS is not the source of the problem.
Hope you can help me. Thanks, Kristof.

Comment: `background !== backgroundColor` (http://jsfiddle.net/3ctnafw8/)

Comment: backgroundColor gives me an error

Comment: well, it works now with backgroundColor. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Since `background` wasn't set, it will be an empty string.

Use `console.log(this.style);` to show all style properties.  You will be able to see that `background` is an empty string and that `backgroundColor` contains a string representing the colour information you set earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`Element.style.background` does not exist and you have not set it for any Element; use `Element.style.backgroundColor`.

```js
var colors = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var rgbColors = [
    "rgb(21,54,217)",
    "rgb(32,255,0)",
    "rgb(43,255,255)",
    "rgb(32,68,103)",
    "rgb(147,54,24)",
    "rgb(255,54,217)"
];
var pickedColor = rgbColors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    colors[i].style.backgroundColor = rgbColors[i];
    colors[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(this.style.backgroundColor);
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>RGB guessing game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> guessing game</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square">1</div>
        <div class="square">2</div>
        <div class="square">3</div>
        <div class="square">4</div>
        <div class="square">5</div>
        <div class="square">6</div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="rgbGame.css" />
    <script src="rgbGame.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```